# .getJSON() callback wont work but API's url works fine

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, api

I am trying to learn more about APIs by playing around with them, and I am having trouble with the Flickr API right now.

My URL that goes into `.getJSON()` works just fine when I type it into chrome manually and it returns a JSON, but my callback function in the below code is not working, meaning that `.getJSON(url)` isn't working.

```
let city='boston';

function gettingFlickrJSON(city1){
    city = city1;
    console.log(1);
    $.getJSON('https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=[my_key_which_i_left_out_for_now]&tags='+city+',city&per_page=10&format=json',function(json){
      console.log(2);
    });
}
```

I tried taking out the

```
&tags='+city+',city...
```

and replacing with a sample run, the callback still didn't work. 
I'm 99% confident the link works because as I said, when typed manually it works. And yes, I have jquery imported into my script.
Here's a link to the documentation for the method I'm trying to use if this is any help. https://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.photos.search.html

Comment: Is there any error? Is the JSON fetched without an error in the Network tab?

Comment: @Xufox Yes, tbh im a rookie at the network tab but it says status: 200, just like my jquery file does too

Comment: What is the sample url you used in Chrome which worked?

Comment: @kujosHeist https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=[my_key_that_works]&tags=nyc&per_page=10&format=json

Comment: Check that the jQuery function is defined with console.log(typeof $ == 'function');

Comment: @iSZ well when I tried console.log(typeof $ == 'getJSON'); it returns false. Did I use that correctly though?

Comment: So if there is a 200 status, you should get _something_. Instead of `console.log(2);`, why not try `console.log(json);` and see what it prints out? You could also try to add a `.fail(`…`)` handler and look out for an error message… just basic debugging.

Comment: @HarunFeraidon That’s not what was suggested. `"getJSON"` can never be the result of `typeof`. Please read carefully.

Comment: @Xufox  Ok now the typeof returns true, and also console.log(json) returns nothing in the console. Neither did console.log(2). The console.log(1) line returns a 1 in the console though, this way I know the method call is working fine, just the json part isnt.

Comment: @iSZ sorry, fixed my code and it returns true now

Comment: @HarunFeraido you should try opening the network inspector in Chrome by pressing f12 and clicking the network tab. The response from flickr should be available for inspection here when you run your request.

Comment: @iSZ the flickr link requent is sent in .12 ms, the Waiting (TTFB) says 390.89 ms, and Content Downloaded is 2.01 ms. Is my issue an asynchronous issue? Does this mean that my code is fine, but I need to add a delay in my method. If so, how do I add the delay?

Comment: @Harun no your anonymous function in getJSON will only run once you get the response. Have a look in the response and see if the expected data is there.

Comment: @iSZ yea the expected data is there. Like I said, when I type the url manually into chrome, the JSON returns. But when I use getJSON, my callback function never runs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use parameter `jsonnocallback=1` in your request if you plan to use the response like this with `$.getJSON` otherwise you have to override the response method and then manipulate it as you like.

Basically, you are misinterpreting `JSON` string with `JSONCallbackfunction`

For watching what is a difference between the 2 responses when used with or without this `parameter`.

Open 2 windows [with](https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=[YOU_API_KEY]&tags='%20%20%20city%20%20%20',city&per_page=50&format=json&nojsoncallback=1) and [without](https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=[YOUR_API_KEY]&tags='%20%20%20city%20%20%20',city&per_page=50&format=json) appending this parameter.You will find out that one returns `JSON` string and the other returns callback function `jsonFlickrApi(response)` which contains a `JSON` object as a parameter. I have added an example code snippet of your code along with my `API` key just to make sure it is working for you I would delete once you respond if it works for you.

If you want to learn a more secure way of working with the callback function see [here](https://mashupguide.net/1.0/html/ch08s07.xhtml)

```js
let city = 'boston';

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#findnow").click(function() {
    $.getJSON('https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=[insert_api_key]&tags=' + city + ',city&per_page=50&format=json&nojsoncallback=1', function(res) {
      for (var key in res.photos.photo) {
        $("#results").append("<li><span class='label label-primary'>" + res.photos.photo[key]['title'] + "</span></li>");
      }
    })

  });
})
```

```css
* {
  margin: 20px auto;
}

body {
  text-align: center;
}

.container {
  border: 2px dashed #000;
  max-height: 250px;
  max-width: 85%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  text-align: left;
}

ul,
li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: block;
  line-height: normal;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<button id="findnow" class="btn btn-default">find photos</button>

<div class="container">
  <p>Below are the list of the photos</p>
  <ul id="results">
  </ul>
</div>
```